# Show AlertDialog from class instance

Tags: android, class, dialog, android-alertdialog, builder

I have created a separate message popup class based on an offical Android example but I can't figure out how to launch this dialog from another activity. The popup class is:

```
public class PopupMessage extends DialogFragment {

    String message = "";

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(message)
               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     //
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

In my other class I have created an instance:

```
import com.mcsapp.PopupMessage;
private PopupMessage popup;
popup = new PopupMessage();
```

When a button is clicked I want to call this. I have this:

```
case R.id.chooseLocationButton: 

            if(editTextLocation.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                popup.message = "Test";
                popup.getDialog().show();
                }

            break;
        }
```

I have tried a variety of "popup" commands but all result in a crash. I'm sure it's simply I just can't find the correct code. The "message" parameter sets just fine so the import is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

popup.show(getFragmentManager(), "PopupMsgFragment");

You may want to change getFragmentManager() with getSupportFragmentManager() if you are using support v4 activity.